# OpenCV: Assertion failed with drawContours()

Tags: c++, opencv, runtime-error, assertion

I'm trying to draw contours from an image. I got a frame from my webcam an extract its contours. Then, I filter them by area, and calling drawContours() to show them. The problem is when I try to draw the filtered contours...if I draw the original ones everything works fine. Here is the code:

```
    size_t contours_size=contours.size();
    bool contour_is_valid[contours_size];
    size_t filtered_contours=0;
    size_t copied_contours=0;
    size_t i;
    double area;
    for(i=0;i<contours_size;i++){
        area=contourArea(contours.at(i),false);
        if(area>minArea && area<maxArea){
            contour_is_valid[i]=true;
            filtered_contours++;
        }
        else{
            contour_is_valid[i]=false;
        }
    }
    area_filtered_contours.resize(filtered_contours);
    for(i=0;i<contours_size;i++){
    if(contour_is_valid[i]==true){
            area_filtered_contours.at(copied_contours).resize(contours.at(i).size());
            copy(contours.at(i).begin(),contours.at(i).end(),back_inserter(area_filtered_contours.at(copied_contours)));
            copied_contours++;
        }
    }
```

contours is the output of findContours() and thus, its a vector< vector < Point > > data as equal as area_filtered_contours. What i am trying to do is to generate another structure like that that have the useful contours in an area sense.
Then

```
drawContours(cnt_img2,contours,_levels <= 0 ? 3 : -1, 255,1,8,hierarchy, std::abs(_levels) );
```

works fine but

```
drawContours(cnt_img2,area_filtered_contours,_levels <= 0 ? 3 : -1, 255,1,8,hierarchy, std::abs(_levels) );
```

give me an assertion error. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Federico

Comment: Maybe this will help, the same error occur with this lines:



          `vector<vector<Point> > test;

  test.resize(1);

  test.at(0).resize(1);

  drawContours(cnt_img2,test,_levels <= 0 ? 3 : -1, 255,1,8,hierarchy, std::abs(_levels) );`

Comment: Can you please provide the assertion error?

Comment: @ØysteinW.

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (hierarchy.total() == ncontours && hierarchy.type() == CV_32SC4) in drawContours, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1604
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1604: error: (-215) hierarchy.total() == ncontours && hierarchy.type() == CV_32SC4 in function drawContours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your assertion says: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (hierarchy.total() == ncontours && hierarchy.type() == CV_32SC4)

Info about the hierarchy from findContours() (opencv.org): Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours.

When you change the number of countures you also have to edit the hierarchy. This is an optional input. Edit this as well or don't use it.

Comment: there's an overload for drawContours, that does not take hierarchy.

Comment: It works now, but the contours are not displayed properly; there are lines coming from (0,0) to the contour and sometimes (when there are no filtered contours) the window holds the last contours

Comment: Does all the contours have lines from (0,0)? Is it only when filtered? And what do you mean by "the window holds the last contours"?

Comment: @ØysteinW. Yes, all the contours, and yes too, only when filtered. Forget about that last thing. Thank you

Comment: @ØysteinW. Done!It was because of back_inserter() in copy function. now the line is

`copy(contours.at(i).begin(),contours.at(i).end(),area_filtered_contours.at(copied_contours).begin());`

I dont know anyway the explanation though. Thank you all!

Comment: And the 'holding' was because i were not erasing the area_filtered_contours before filtering again (when the next frame comes).

Comment: Glad you sort it out yourself! Nothing is better!